# Jenkins pipeline file parameter message

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline file parameter defined like below

```
def inputFile = input message: 'Upload the deploy.yaml file', parameters: [file(name: 'deploy.yaml',description: 'The file should be in YAML format')]
```

But in the pipeline mouse over it shows a default message like

```
Upload the deploy.yaml file
The paused input step uses advanced input options. Please redirect to approve.
```

[image]
redirect part have a hyperlink, where after clicking I can browse a file and upload.

But how to customize the default message in mouse over to something meaningful like "click here to upload file"

Comment: You can change the value for your `message` argument to the `input` method.

Comment: I wont to change the test "The paused input step uses advanced input options. Please redirect to approve."